# Save product programmatically change category assignment

Tags: magento

Magento CE 1.9.0.1, saving product programmatically after change msrp programmatically change all product category assignments. See code below:

```
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$skus = array ('SKU1','SKU2','SKU3');
$object = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
foreach ($skus as $sku) {
    $_product = $object->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
    $id = $_product->getId();
    $product = $object->load($id);
    $product->setMsrp(10.99);
    $product->save();
}
```

There are more than 1000 SKUs. After running this script, all category assignments are changed. Every product has multiple category assignments. The total number of products for each category is changed after running the script. Why the category assignment is changed after running this script?

Comment: I'm trying to find a question in this question, but I can't.

Comment: Sorry, basically the question is why category assignment is changed?

Comment: Please edit your original question by clicking the |edit| link.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

```
$product->save(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've solved by changing the database directly rather than using product->save().